# Prevent T4 generation for regenerate existing file

Tags: c#, automation, code-generation, t4

I've a little T4 script which generates a lot of empty method defintions for me. The T4 generator reads a text file to generate all these methods defintions.

After T4 generated my C# file, I've to implement some logic into each generated method. The problem is, if I'll change the text file, I've to regenerate the C# file. The generator will remove all my changes and create a new file.

Is there a way to keep the original file (which was also generated) and just append generated code (if the generated method not exist) into the C# script?

Comment: Re-design your template to generate partial class(-es) and partial methods. Implement your logic as a partial method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I'll implement partial methods I've no gain using T4. Okay, here's my example: I am writing an emulator. For each operation code I've to create a method. With T4 I'll generate all these empty methods to decrease time for writing all these methods manually. If I'm using partial methods, I've to write each method manually again, so there is no gain for me using partial methods. Have you another idea, or should I solve my problem with a different solution.

Comment: I see. IMO, T4 can't help you here - it completely re-writes output.

Comment: What about making the class holding the methods a base class and then override those methods in another class.  This way you can regenerate without fear the base class and any work done in the derived class will not be overwritten.